# Wrong strlen returning char Matrix

Tags: arrays, c, strlen

```
char t[2][5] = {"  *  ","  *  "};
printf("%d\n",strlen(t[0]));
```

Output:

```
11
```

Why is this happening and how can I print just the length of the first string?

Each string should have a size of 5 (two white spaces plus asterisk plus two whites spaces).

Comment: Your arrays of [5] chars cannot hold "  *  " and also the terminating \0. So the \0 won't be there, and you won't have valid strings. Make them [6] instead.

Comment: 5 is not enough room to store `"  *  "`  That's two spaces, an asterisk, and two spaces, and a null terminator.  That requires 6 chars to store.  (Does this not generate a compiler warning?) The first string doesn't have room for the terminator, so it runs into the next characters (`strlen` just counts chars until it finds a NUL) so it happened to count the 10 chars that fit, plus 1 more random non-null garbage character that happened to be at the end (lucky) and then there must have been a NUL after that too because it stopped at 11.  Good thing your house didn't catch fire too!  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strlen()` only works on null-terminated strings, but the strings in your array are not null-terminated.  So your code has *undefined behavior*.

The string literal `"  *  "` has **6 characters**, *including* the null-terminator, but your array only allows space for **5 characters** per string, so the null-terminators are getting chopped off.

Also, `strlen()` return a `size_t` rather than an `int`, so `%d` is the wrong format specifier to use in `printf`-style functions when printing a `size_t` value. You need to use `%zu` instead.

Try this:

```
char t[2][6] = {"  *  ","  *  "};
printf("%zu\n", strlen(t[0]));
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/2Ww_oPrzg)

Now you will see `5` as expected.

This would also work, too:

```
const char* t[2] = {"  *  ","  *  "};
printf("%zu\n", strlen(t[0]));
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r7qbya-ym)

Comment: Now you will see `5` instead of _undefined behavior_.  (anything could have happened -- the `11` was a fluke.  Could just as easily have crashed scanning memory looking for a 0 char.)

Answer (score 1):

```
//1
char t[2][6];
memcpy(t[0], "  *  ", 6);
memcpy(t[1], "  *  ", 6);

//2
char* tt[2] = { "  *  ","  *  " };

//3
char ttt[2][6] = { ' ',' ','*',' ',' ',0,' ',' ','*',' ',' ',0 };

//4
char (*tttt)[6] = (char(*)[6]) "  *  " "  *  ";
```